# Power Bi - Autorefresh the PowerBi report with import Query

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-data-explorer

I have a Power BI report that is using the Import query method (Source - getData - Azure Data Explorer Kusto)

I have completed couple of reports with Import Query mode and I could not setup Auto refresh. Then I modified the report to Direct Query mode and still I could not see the Auto refresh Option. Could you please clarify How do I set up Scheule Autorefresh in Power Bi reports.

I am using Power BI desktop, Should I start a fresh report from Direct query mode instead of modifying the existing report. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Please see I posted an answer which matched with my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the inputs. My requirement was to use Import mode (For better performance) and refresh the dataset every 5 minutes. It can be acheived using the Power Automate flow. I share the link for reference. I already tested and it works fine. with this schedule flow you can refresh the dataset (from every 1 minute)

Refresh your Power BI dataset using Microsoft Flow
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/refresh-your-power-bi-dataset-using-microsoft-flow/

Also you can use Azure Logic App to create Schedule Workflows for PowerBI dataset refresh. You may have to check the cost involved for using Logic App, Storage acc etcc

https://srini-velamakanti.medium.com/refresh-a-power-bi-dataset-using-azure-logic-app-8b8d7529876

Comment: Sure I just did . Also edited my answer to use another method which is Dataset refresh using Azure LogicApp

Answer (score 2):

You need to publish the report from the PBI desktop (see last menu item):

[image]

once you do this, you can configure the refresh schedule as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh).

Comment: The schedule refresh is limited to every 30 Mins. I have req to refresh every 5 mins or less. Is there a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have published your report to workspace online. Refer: [Power BI refresh types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#power-bi-refresh-types)

"Power BI does not import data over connections that operate in DirectQuery mode."

> For import models, you can find the refresh schedule in the "Scheduled
> refresh" section of the Datasets tab. For composite datasets, the
> "Scheduled refresh" section is located in the Optimize Performance
> section.

[image]

**Import Query Method:**

[image]

**Direct Query Method:**

[image]

Comment: The schedule refresh is limited to every 30 Mins. I have req to refresh every 5 mins or less. Is there a way to do it.

Comment: The direct query will provide you with the latest data, there is no refresh needed.

Comment: ok Thanks. let me check and will use performance analyzer to check the Direct Query mode.